# Identifying unused JS script files in the project

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I had taken over a project which has been developed using ASP.NET MVC, Bootstrap, Jquery and SQL Server. Understand that developers use this as a base project template and reuse most of the code from here for any new developement.

Within Scripts folder, there are 80+ JS files and am doubting that over the period of time they would have got accumulated. None of the developers have any clue on whether all those .js files are used in this project. Looking for ideas/help to find out a way to identify all files which aren't used anymore in the code & can be removed?

**Update:** 
In Bundle.config I see only entries for these:

```
"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
"~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
"~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
"~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
"~/Scripts/respond.js"));
"~/Content/css")
"~/Content/bootstrap.css","~/Content/site.css"));
```

Rest of them are scattered across layout, adminlayout & other .cshtml files as `<script src=....></script>` references.

Comment: You could look at the bundle config as a first line of defense? Whatever isn't in there would probably be safe to remove unless there are direct <script> tags referencing the files outside of the bundle.

Comment: Looks like somebody has down voted it. Not sure what is the problem with my question. If something needs to be clarified pls post it as a comment than down voting as I am trying to identify a real solution for my problem! Thanks.

Comment: @MarkC. Yes there are lots of <script> tag references in the project across multiple files. For example in layout page itself we could see 10+ <script> tag reference.

Comment: not an easy task I am afraid :( what I would suggest is to create a new folder and place your new js files on that folder and when you encounter a major work on a new page you shift the only required js files on that page to the app folder. its gonna be a tiresome process

Answer (score 2):

Check if this [extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28650fe9-f41e-4db9-9d61-4e3f59c85b5e) is what you are looking for:

Comment: Thanks for your response will check that extension.